# How can I change my C++ to use /std:c++17 in Jetbrains Rider?

Tags: c++, jetbrains-rider

I have a problem with my Rider IDE using C++98 I guess (tested using __cplusplus) and when using inline constexpr it says

> main.cpp(2, 22): [C7525] inline variables require at least '/std:c++17'

How can I change it to use cpp+17?

I tried looking for it in .vcxproj. I heard I can change it there but still could not find anything there. Do you know how can I do this?

Comment: I didn't even know that Rider IDE supported C++.  I thought it was just for **.NET**.

Comment: yes it has c++ and is one of favorite ide when you want to work with unreal engine i guess. having all the fancy tooltips and autoCompletes for macros and such

Comment: Cool, I didn't know that.  I <3 JetBrains folks, they make awesome software.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create a C++ project.
2. Right click the project in the solution window and click Properties
3. Select a configuration (Debug or Release)
4. In the general tab, chose your C++ Language Standard.

Comment: There is no general tab

Answer (score -1):

/Project/ItemDefinitionGroup[1]/ClCompile/LanguageStandard
Just here. Enter 'stdcpp17'.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34401682)